# Is there a way to short the general education market?

Tags: shorting-securities, education

Or in part to short companies involved in supporting the current state of the education market? (book sellers, equipment vendors, universities etc..)

Answer (score 3):

There are several public companies that have large exposure to that market, mainly for profit colleges.

They react to news about regulation or student loans and abysmal reports. You just have to find those companies and watch them like a hawk